# H2 Database Connection

Tags: java, h2

I need to ping H2 Database in Java.

In order to do that I'm sending a GET request to ip_db:port:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

But all I get is ClientProtocolException.

When I try to open ip_db:port in Firefox, I get the following info (slightly edited for readability):

```
90047BVersion mismatch, driver version is "0" but server version is "12"яяяя_їXorg.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Version mismatch, driver version is "0" but server version is "12" [90047-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Here's H2 log:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: my_ip" [90067-173]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:160)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:407)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:295)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:105)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:90)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at org.h2.tools.CreateCluster.process(CreateCluster.java:137)
        at org.h2.tools.CreateCluster.runTool(CreateCluster.java:85)
        at org.h2.tools.CreateCluster.main(CreateCluster.java:52)
```

What do I need to do to ping the database?

Comment: Ping a database? Are you trying to establish aliveness? Are you perhaps confusing JDBC URL with HTTP URL? What is your `url`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to establish aliveness. Probably confusing. url is http://ip_db:9092 - the same ip I'm tring to reach with Firefox.

Comment: Well then I would say you've accomplished your goal - if the DB wasn't alive you'd get a [`ConnectException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html) instead :-)

Comment: I would open a connection and keep it open, and then when you want to check whether the connection is alive, run a simple query such as `select 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this method

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
    console.append("CONNECTED" + '\n');
    if(conn.isValid(1000){
    //DO WHATEVER FOR ALIVENESS
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    console.append(e.getMessage() + '\n');
    }
```